# The procedure entry point QueryFullProcessImageNameA could not be locatedin the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2008, windows-xp

I am trying to run a program on Visual Studio on a XP computer and i am getting the error in the heading. I have all the service packs for XP and VS. Never seen anything like this before so i really dont have a clue. Anyone seen this problem before or know what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API is aviable since Vista see also the MSDN chapter requirements:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx

So far that API is simply not aviable. Try to search something equal for XP.